# toolbar text item gets cropped

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is a very weird behavior happening with the toolbar, I have the following:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        HStack {
            Imagegoeshere...
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            Text("Polkadot")
            // Text(coinInfo?.name ?? "-")
        }
    }
}
```

Just like that it displays correct the image and on the right the name "Polkadot" (that's for testing), if I replace that `Text("Polkadot")` with the real value (which contains the exact text with no spaces) it crops it: `Text(coinInfo?.name ?? "-")`

This is how it looks with the testing text:

[image]

and this is how it looks with the real value yet the same exact text:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident just now I found the solution, still I have no idea why this happens, this is how it got fixed:

Replace the `HStack` with `LazyHStack`

Comment: If someone understands why this fixed it please shine in

Comment: Let me assume that `coinInfo` is not ready when toolbar is constructed first time, so it preserves constant space (as HStack does), but LasyHStack knows that content might be loaded later, so updated (or informs parent that should be updated) correctly when property is changed. Something like that.

Comment: Correct the name might not be ready when the view is loaded since it's coming from the API, but I would assume that the HStack kind of dynamically changes as well no? At least in other views it does changes once the data changes in something like a `@State var` @Asperi

Comment: Often, but not always, toolbar, navigation bar... actually everything bridging to UIKit... it is not so transparent as we'd like it to be, unfortunately. I hope WWDC22 will show further more native SwiftUI components and separation of existed... at least they move towards that.

Comment: That would make sense, looking foward to WWDC22 as well! Thanks for the clarifications @Asperi